# Colour geom_segment in ggplot2 according to segment length

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a graph that displays the distortion of points by connecting the original and new location. I would like to visualise the level of distortion by colouring the segments according to their length. As visible in the uncoloured graph the distortion centre is at around [0,300] and amplifies towards [300,0].

[image: Current uncoloured version of the graph]

I was hoping to find a way to feed the segment length into the colour option of geom_segment, but I could not find an internal way of ggplot2 to do so. Do I have to manually compute the length and store it in the data frame, or is there a more elegant way? I was hoping something along the lines of feeding the respective segments length property to colour and use some colour range to signify length.

**Edit:** [A link to the data on display.](https://polybox.ethz.ch/index.php/s/KCDZl4rtXz4tvhe)

As well as some code:

```
library(readr)
library(ggplot2)

data<-read_csv("distortedGraph.csv",col_names = F)

ggplot(data = data) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = X2, xend = X4, y = X3, yend = X5)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-50, 350))+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-50, 350))+
  coord_fixed()
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example, thanks.

Comment: Not sure I understand the downvotes? Yes, a reprex would be good but the question itself is pretty clear?

Comment: `library(ggforce); ?geom_link` maybe.

Comment: Basically you can just do `ggplot(dat, aes(x1, y1, xend = x2, yend = y2, color = sqrt((x1 - x2)^2 + (y1 - y2)^2))) + geom_segment()`. But without data, no complete answer.

Comment: I provided the requested data..

Comment: @Axeman your manual computation would certainly solve it, but I would like to know if there is a library out there that does something similar. If you post it as an answer with no other responses I would gladly accept it.

Comment: @markus I will try ggforce and check whether I can resolve this. Thank you for the pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is easiest to just manually give the distance formula, it's not all that complicated. `geom_segment` does not calculate a distance statistic for you. Add a nice color palette and you should be good to go:

```
ggplot(dat, 
       aes(x = X2, xend = X4, y = X3, yend = X5,
           color = sqrt((X2 - X4)^2 + (X3 - X5)^2))) +
  geom_segment(alpha = 0.5) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-50, 350))+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-50, 350))+
  coord_fixed() +
  viridis::scale_color_viridis(name = 'distance')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the example solution, however, you used X1 instead of X2, so the colours are off. Compare the x aesthetics with the variables used in the length computation.

Answer (score 2):

While @Axeman provided the exact answer I was looking for, I looked into @markus's comment and concluded that `geom_link` in `ggforce` would provide a different, but also interesting analysis of the level of distortion each point experienced by applying a gradient along the distortion line:

```
library(ggforce)
ggplot(data = data) +
  geom_link(aes(x = X2, xend = X4, y = X3, yend = X5,colour = ..index..)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-50, 350))+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-50, 350))+
  coord_fixed()+
  viridis::scale_color_viridis(name = 'distortion', option = "C", direction = -1)
```

[image: Plot degree of distortion with gradient]