# Draw a geom_segment line with a colour gradient? (or is there another way to emphasize start vs end?)

Tags: r, ggplot2, line

I have two sets of latitude & longitude variables for a large number of rows in my data frame (~100,000). I am trying to make a plot that connects those two sets of coordinates (i.e, ~100,000 lines that go from *latitude1,longitude1* to *latitude2,longitude2*), using geom_segment, with a very low alpha to make the lines transparent because there are so many lines.

I would like to emphasize the starting points and end points of those lines, and I reckoned the best way to do that would would be to have a colour gradient from start to end (let's say green to red).

Is it possible to draw a geom_segment line with a colour gradient? If not, do you know another way to emphasize start vs end with so many lines?

(I realize that it could end up looking messy because there are so many lines, but I suspect that many of them go in the same direction..)

Here is some example data of 5 rows (but in reality I have ~100,000, so it should be somewhat computationally efficient):

```
 example.df <- as.data.frame(matrix(c(1,435500,387500,320000,197000,
                                      2,510500,197500,513000,164000,
                                      3,164500,40500,431000,385000,
                                      4,318500,176500,316000,172000,
                                      5,331500,188500,472000,168000),
                                      nrow=5, ncol=5, byrow = TRUE))
  colnames(example.df) <- c("ID","longitude.1","latitude.1",
                            "longitude.2","latitude.2")

 library(ggforce)
 ggplot(example.df, aes(longitude.1, latitude.1))+
 geom_link(aes(x=longitude.1, y=latitude.1,
               xend=longitude.2, yend=latitude.2, 
               alpha=0.5), col="black")+
 coord_equal()
```

This produces these five lines:
[image]

I would like these lines to start as blue at their first longitute-latitude coordinate point and end as red at the second longitute-latitude coordinate point.

Comment: `ggforce` has geoms that do this: https://ggforce.data-imaginist.com/reference/geom_link.html

Comment: Thank you @camille! I figured out how geom_link can make the line go more transparent, but I can't seem to figure out how to make it change colours from the start to the end of the line... any ideas on how to achieve that? Many thanks again!

Comment: Maybe if you add a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Without seeing your data, I don't know how it would be any different from the color gradient example in the vignette I posted

Comment: My apologies! I have now produced an example of five lines. Many thanks again for your help!

Comment: @Abdel: You can always emphasize start and end by plotting arcs instead of lines (by adding the `arrow` option inside `geom_segment`). Would that help?

Comment: Thanks you for the suggestion @symbolrush, but I'm afraid that would not work well with the many lines I have in the actual data (~100,000). I think transparent lines wit changing colours between start and end would work best with so many lines...

Comment: Related: [Colour geom_segment in ggplot2 according to segment length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48058055/colour-geom-segment-in-ggplot2-according-to-segment-length)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `ggforce` approach seems like the best approach to what you are asking. Your code was almost what you were looking for, but I think you may have overlooked the `colour = stat(index)` statement inside the mapping. I assume that the `index` is a statistic that `geom_link()` calculates under the hood to interpolate the colours.

```
ggplot(example.df, aes(longitude.1, latitude.1))+
  geom_link(aes(x = longitude.1, y = latitude.1,
                xend = longitude.2, yend = latitude.2, 
                colour = stat(index)), lineend = "round") +
  scale_colour_gradient(low = "red", high = "green") +
  coord_equal()
```

[image]

A word of warning though, seeing as you intend to plot many lines; if you use an `alpha =` for `geom_link()` you can clearly see segmentation of the lines:

```
ggplot(example.df, aes(longitude.1, latitude.1))+
  geom_link(aes(x = longitude.1, y = latitude.1,
                xend = longitude.2, yend = latitude.2, 
                colour = stat(index)), lineend = "round", size = 10, alpha = 0.1) +
  scale_colour_gradient(low = "red", high = "green") +
  coord_equal()
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use arrowheads to indicate end positions as follows:

```
ggplot(example.df, aes(longitude.1, latitude.1)) +
  geom_segment(aes(xend = longitude.2, yend = latitude.2),
               arrow = arrow()) +
  coord_equal()
```

[image]

A potential downside is that very short segments may be overemphasized with the arrows.

Hope this helps!