# Gradient line segment using ggplot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to add a line segment intervals to a `ggplot`. However, I am trying to make the line segments a gradient that fades the alpha to zero at each end of the interval.

For example, if I create a plot that includes some intervals, like so:

```
    library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(
  name = c('x1', 'x2', 'x3'),
  value = c(0.251, 0.207, 0.182),
  seg = c(0.027, 0.028, 0.049)
)

p <- df %>%
  ggplot() + aes(x=name, y=value) +
  geom_segment(aes(x=name, xend=name, y=(value - seg), yend=(value + seg),
                   col = name), 
               size = 5) +
  geom_point(aes(x=name, y = value), shape = 18, size = 5, color = "black") +
  theme_bw() +
  xlab('Name') +
  ylab("Value") 

p
```

This produces a plot like this:
[image: interval plot]

However, I am trying to figure out a way to turn those line segments into a thicker bar, that fades the alpha to zero at each end.

Something like the plot below (which can be found [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggdist/vignettes/slabinterval.html))... but Im not sure how to create this style of plot with my data.
[image: gradient interval]

For clarity, I am just trying to recreate the coloured gradient intervals from the plot above.

**EDIT**

As per one of the comments, I tried using `geom_link` for this... but I cant seem to get it to work correctly.

To begin, I created a vector of alpha values to pass to `geom_link` like so:

```
alpLow <- seq(from = 0, to = 1, length.out = 150)
alpHigh <- rev(alpLow)
alp <- c(alpLow, alpHigh)
```

And then used this in `geom_link`:

```
p <- df %>%
  ggplot() + aes(x=name, y=value) +
  geom_link(aes(x = name, y = (value - seg),
                xend = name, yend = (value + seg), 
                colour = stat(index)), lineend = "round", size = 5, alpha = alp)
```

Which produces this:
[image: gradient seqment]

As you can see, it only applies the gradient at the start and end of the 1st and last line segment.

Furthermore, Im not entirely pleased with the aesthetic of using `geom_link` as it seems to link together points (which are visible when you zoom in)... I was really hoping for a solid bar that fades the alpha.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R: is it possible to draw a geom\_segment line with a colour gradient? (or is there another way to emphasize start vs end?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55752424/r-is-it-possible-to-draw-a-geom-segment-line-with-a-colour-gradient-or-is-the)

Comment: I am guessing, the problem is we have a summary data, no enough data points to make a gradient?

Comment: I am guessing I should use some type of scale_alpha argument. But Im not sure what to use. But I will update my question to make it more clear

Comment: Additionally, I don't feel my question is a duplicate, as in the link you provide @tjebo, they only provide a single value for the alpha. That is not what Im trying to achieve

Comment: I cant seem to get it to work correctly using `geom_link`. I will update the question with some additional code using `geom_link`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope the below is sufficiently different to merit a new answer. I have had a bit more time to look into the link which you have provided. {ggdist} has those gradient interval stats - they need the underlying data and not summary data for calculation of their density.

Assuming that you have summarised data in a way that those values represent the distribution of your data (e.g., a normal distribution), you can use this in order to recreate data based on those values. I have here created normal distributions for each group, using your values as mean and standard deviation, and then you can use `ggdist::stat_gradientinterval`. But you can also create other distributions of course.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggdist)

df <- data.frame(
  name = c('x1', 'x2', 'x3'),
  value = c(0.251, 0.207, 0.182),
  seg = c(0.027, 0.028, 0.049)
)

df_norm <- 
df %>%
  split(., .$name) %>%
  map(function(x) rnorm(100, x$value, x$seg)) %>%
  bind_rows() %>%
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "name", values_to = "value")
  
ggplot(df_norm, aes(x=name, y=value, fill= name)) +
  ggdist::stat_gradientinterval() +
  theme_bw() +
  labs(x= 'Name', y = "Value")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-12-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Use `ggforce::geom_link`

alpha = stat(index) is just one option, from the documentation.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggforce)

df <- data.frame(
  name = c('x1', 'x2', 'x3'),
  value = c(0.251, 0.207, 0.182),
  seg = c(0.027, 0.028, 0.049)
)


df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=name, y=value)) +
  geom_link(aes(x=name, xend=name, yend=value + seg,
                   col = name, alpha = rev(stat(index))), 
               size = 5) +
  geom_link(aes(x=name, xend=name, yend=value - seg,
                   col = name, alpha = rev(stat(index))), 
               size = 5) +
  
  geom_point(aes(x=name, y = value), shape = 18, size = 5, color = "black") +
  theme_bw() +
  labs(x= 'Name', y = "Value")
```

[image]

Comment: regarding that pointillistisc look - you can control the number of points with the n argument.